# Confuse about error and reject in Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

All:

I am pretty new to JS Promise, there is one confuse when it comes to Promise chaining, say I have a promise chaining like:

```
var p = new Promise(function(res, rej){
})
.then(
    function(data){
    }, 
    function(err){
    })
.then(
    function(data){
    }, 
    function(err){
    })
.catch(
    function(err){
    })
```

What confuse me:

1. When the function(err) get called and when the catch get called?
2. How to resolve and reject in `then`?

Thanks

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24663315/1048572) will help you

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, so from that diagram in your answer, the error can steer to either resolve function or reject function of next chained the() at any time depends on I use return value or throw error , right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Which is often not expected by people who do nothing (return `undefined`) but want the next `catch` to get the error as well, for which they need to rethrow it.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, so could I make sure the catch will handle exception no matter what error happens at any level of chained then(), the only ugly way I can think is keep using throw in reject function part at every level of then, is there a better way to handle that?

Comment: Just omit the onreject callbacks you're passing to `then`, and the rejection will be passed on automatically.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, this helps

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The formular for using a Promise is:

```js
var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  var condition = doSomething();

  if (condition) {
    resolve(data);
  } else {
    reject(err);
  }

});
```

There is nothing special about `.catch`, it is just sugar for `.then (undefined, func)`, but `.catch` more clearly communicates that it is purely an error handler.

If a `Promise` does not resolve and no rejection callback is provided in it, it skips forward to the next `.then` in the chain with a rejection callback in it. The rejection callback is the `reject(err)`.

For more detailed explanations see: [Javascript Promises - There and Back again](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/).

---

That is: in your example the .`catch` only gets called if the preceding rejection callback has an error in it. That is there is an error in the `reject(err)` function itself - which has nothing to do with the preceding `Promise` not resolving.

You can essentially limit yourself to a rejection callback in the `.catch` at you end of the `.then` chain. Any `Error` in any `.then` will then fall through to the `.catch`. One subtlety though: any error in the `.catch` is not caught.

Comment: I believe the executor function for a Promise Object accepts the RESOLVE callback first.

Comment: Not sure what you exactly mean @BinaekSarkar. The Promise should be constructed so that is only resolves if it succeeds with the task is has been given.

Comment: What I meant was that the Promise executor function takes the RESOLVES function as the first argument. `var p = new Promise(function(reject, resolve)` should be `var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject)`

Answer (score 6):

The important thing to know is that the .then() method is always chained *onto* a Promise, and it returns a *new* Promise whose value and resolved/rejected state is based on what the function given to it returned.

In your example, if the original Promise resolves, then the first function in your first .then() will get called with the resolved value. If it returns a value then whatever value *it* returns will then get ultimately passed into the first function in your *second* .then().  The function in catch will never get called.

If the Promise rejects, the second function in your first .then() will get called with the rejected value, and whatever *value* it returns will become a new resolved Promise which passes into the first function of your second then.  Catch is never called here either.  It's only if the Promise rejects and you *keep returning rejected Promises or throwing errors in both your `function(err){}` functions* that you'll get the `function(err){}` in your catch block called.

To resolve in your `function(data){}` functions, all you need to do is return a value (or return a Promise/thenable that later resolves). 
To reject, you would need to either throw an error, actually *cause* an error, return a new Promise that eventually rejects, or explicitly return `Promise.reject(::some value::)`.

To resolve in your `function(err){}` blocks, all you need to do is return a new value.  You could also return a Promise, in which case that Promise is what will be returned (eventually resolving or rejecting).

In general, it's not wise to define both the resolved and rejected path in the same .then() though: `PROMISE.then(fn).catch(fn)` is a much safer/clearer practice, because then any errors in the first .then() will be caught by catch.  If you do `PROMISE.then(fn, fn)` instead though, if an error happens in the first function it would NOT get caught by the second: some later chained on method would have to catch it.

Comment: " if the Promise resolves, then the first function in your first .then() will get called with the resolved value"  is only true if the resolved value is not a  promise object (or thenable object). "and whatever value it returns will become a new resolved Promise which passes into the first function of your second then." is _totally_ incorrect. If the value it returns is a promise, it holds up calling then/catch handlers of a `.then` returned promise. If it does not return a promise, the value returned is passed to a .then handler. Downvoted.

Comment: I do cover/mention exactly that later on, but I've edited to clarify that at first I'm just talking about the case of returning values. Imo, when starting out, it's important to first get the basic idea that whatever the function fn in .then(fn) returns will determine what sort of new Promise is created (what value it wraps) and that chaining pure, value-returning functions with P.then(fn1).then(fn2).then(fn3) is akin to Promise.resolve(compose(f1,f2,f3)(Pvalue)). That you can also return Promises/thenables is a more complex idea, but covering the basics first is a good idea.

Comment: @Dtipson Thanks, after a few tries, I find this answer is most make sense to me.

Comment: The [Promises A+ spec](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec)  does not mention of creating a new Promise wrapper around the return value of a .then( onfulfill) function, nor is it described in the [ECMAScript 2015 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-performpromisethen). There is no inherent creation of a new Promise wrapper for a then(fn) function's return value.

Comment: "7. then must return a promise" which for a returned value in an onFulfilled leads to the Promise Resolution Procedure which "fulfills promise with the value x"

We're not talking about "new" Promise((resolve,reject)=>...) here, but rather that each step in the chain is most certainly a fresh Promise in the sense that it is not the SAME promise as what it chained off of.  Each step in the chain can be assigned to a value, passed around, and have different things chained off of it.

Comment: You can confirm that it's a new Promise each time just by a strict equality test, btw.
const g = Promise.resolve(2); g === g.then(x=>x);// false

Answer (score 3):

1. Note the example executor function in

   `var p = new Promise(function(res, rej){});`

   is incomplete. An actual executor function supplied to the Promise constructor must call its first argument (`res`) to resolve the constructed promise, or its second argument (`rej`) to reject the promise. These calls are normally made asynchronously but don't have to be in ES6.
2. When a promise is resolved with a Promise object (or any object with a `.then` property which is a function) nothing happens until the promise object supplied in resolution itself becomes **fulfilled** or **rejected**. Fulfilled values are passed to `.then` `onFulfilled` handlers, rejected values are passed to `.then` `onRejected` handlers/listeners/callbacks (depending on your terminology).
3. But when a promise is resolved with a non promise (like) object, listeners supplied as the first parameter to `.then` are called with the resolution value.
4. When a promise is rejected with any value, listeners supplied as the second parameter to `.then`, or first parameter to `.catch`, are called  with the rejected value.
5. `.catch` is a euphemism for calling `.then` with the supplied argument as second parameter and omitting the first parameter, as in

   `Promise.prototype.catch = function( listener) { return this.then(null, listener);};`
6. The behavior of `.then` registered `onFulfill` and `onReject` functions is the same. To reject a chained promise throw an error. To fulfill a chained promise return a non promise value. To hold up a chained promise return a promise (or promise like) object.

   ---
7. (Update) When a parameter supplied to `.then( onFulfill, onReject)` is missing or not a function object, processing is equivalent to supplying a dummy function from:

   ```
   function onFulfill( data) { return data;}
   function onReject( err) { throw err;}
   ```

   This is the usual case when calling `then` or `catch` with a single argument.

Comment: *.catch is a euphemism for calling .then with the supplied argument as second parameter and omitting the first parameter.* or put another way, `.catch(fn)` === `.then(null, fn)` - though, the `null` could be any non-function

Comment: In regards to #2: when .then returns a value, it acts like "map" operation (that is, it runs the function on the wrapped value and returns a Promise wrapping the returned value).  But when it returns a Promise/thenable, it acts like flatMap/chain operation instead.  Which is to say, it unnests: instead of returning a Promise(Promise()) as one would expect from a simple map operation, it instead just returns the internal Promise().